# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while trying to install PyCBC

Tags: software-installation, sudo, pip, error-handling, segmentation-fault

I am using ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Desktop) and tried to install the package PyCBC according to the first line provided at https://pycbc.org/pycbc/latest/html/install.html

That is, I ran:

```
pip3 install lalsuite pycbc
```

I found people discussing a similar error here:

https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/59

And so I tried upgrading my pip with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

and that actually allowed me to install lalsuite successfully (which was giving me errors before) but not pycbc. The error I get is:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

with no prior error messages.

Does this happen if you try the same on any ubuntu or am I missing something here? I should note that this is a new ubuntu I just created using VirtualBox so there is nothing else installed.

Do you guys also get the same error when trying:

```
pip3 install lalsuite pycbc
```

Could it be because: "at this time, PyCBC supports Python2. Python3 support is under development" (from https://pycbc.org/pycbc/latest/html/install.html)

And just as a quick aside what is the difference between this installation and developing PyCBC given that I just want to use the functions provided?

Comment: We don't even know what release of Ubuntu you are talking about?  19.04 desktop?  19.04 server?  18.04 desktop? 18.04 server? Ubuntu Core 18? or other variations or releases.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue with the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
```

(Note there is no 3).

And then:

```
pip install lalsuite pycbc
```

All seems to be working now. I suspect it had something to do with:

"at this time, PyCBC supports Python2. Python3 support is under development" (from  https://pycbc.org/pycbc/latest/html/install.html). If anyone has a better answer please let me know but for now this seemed to fix it.